# C++ OOP pointer trick in java

Tags: java, c++, oop, pointers

I'm new to Java, but I have quite some experience with C++. There is something I want to do in Java that can only be accomplished with pointers in C++. Since code explains more than a thousand words:

```
class Parent;
class Kid;

class Parent{
public:
    Parent();
private:
    Kid *kid;
};

class Kid{
public:
    Kid(Parent*);
private:
    Parent *parent;
};

Parent::Parent(){
    //give self
    kid = new Kid(this);
}

Kid::Kid(Parent* parent){
    //kid can now adress the class containing the instance
    parent = parent;
}
```

So, is this possible in Java, and how?

Comment: So you are looking to create a circular reference ?

Comment: Java has references and the `this` keyword. You should be able to do a lot of what you'd do with pointers in C++ using Java's references. You just can't do things like pointer arithmetic or taking the address of a primitive or a pointer to pass it "by reference".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct that in Java there is no "pointer", but in practice, all references to objects function very much like pointers. So, whenever a variable, field, or argument refers to an object, it is "pointing" to some specific object in memory.

So, in Java, your code would look like:

```
class Parent {
    private Kid kid;
    public Parent() {
        kid = new Kid(this);
    }
}

class Kid {
    private Parent parent;
    public Kid(Parent p) {
        parent = p;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is easy in Java. All Java variables of Object type are references. So the Kid can have a Parent field that references the Parent object.

```
public class Parent{
    private Kid kid;
    public Parent( ) {
        kid = new Kid( this );
    }
}

public class Kid {
    private Parent parent;
    public Kid( Parent p ) {
       parent = p;  // Copies the *reference* to the parent, not the object itself.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In java every object you create with new is in fact a reference, i.e. a pointer.
So just create everything with "new" and you'll be fine.

```
public class Parent{
public Parent() { kid = new Kid(this) }
private Kid kid;
}

public class Kid{

public Kid(Parent parent){ this.parent = parent }
private Parent parent;
};
```